# How to know the details of calculated ActualWidth/ActualHeight

Tags: wpf, actualwidth, actualheight

We were working on a WPF application project, and the '*about 1px problem*' puzzled us a lot.

Finally, we guess maybe the problem about `Width` and `ActualWidth`.

For instance, we set `Border` `width` to **160px**, and the actual width would be **160.4px**.

Any method can help to find the details of the added **0.4px**?

Comment: Snaps to device pixels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using tools like "WPF Inspector" or Snopp. This might help to detect problems at runtime.